# How to check if subset is empty in R

Tags: r, subset, data-science, boxplot, outliers

I have a set of data with weight with time (t), I need to identify outliers of weight for every time (t), after which I need to send a notification email.

I'm using bloxplot($out) to identify the outliers, it seems to work, but I'm not sure if:

1. It's the correct way to use the boxplot?
2. I can't detect if the boxplot has no outlier or if its empty (or maybe, I'm using a wrong technique)
3. Or possibly the subset itself is empty (could be the root cause)

For now, I just need to trap the empty subset and check if out variable is empty or not.

Below is my R script code:

```
#i am a comment, and the compiler doesn't care about me

#load our libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(mailR)

#some variables to be used later 
from<-""
to<-""

getwd()
setwd("C:\\Temp\\rwork")

#read the data file into a data(d) variable
d<-read.csv("testdata.csv", header=TRUE) #file

#get the current time(t)
t <-format(Sys.time(),"%H")

#create a subset of d based on t
sbset<-subset(d,Time==t)

#identify if outlier exists then send an email report
out<-boxplot(sbset$weight)$out

if(length(out)!=0){
  #create a boxplot of the subset
  boxplot(sbset$weight)

  subject = paste("Attention: An Outlier is detected for Scheduled Job Run on Hour ",t)
  message = toString(out) #sort(out)
}else{
  subject = paste("No Outlier Identified")
  message = ""
}

email<-send.mail(from=from,
          to=to,
          subject=subject,
          body=message,
          html=T,
          smtp=list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    port = 465,
                    user.name = from,
                    passwd = "", #password of sender email
                    ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate=TRUE,
          send=TRUE)
```

**DATA**

```
weight,Time,Chick,x
42,0,1,1
51,2,1,1
59,4,1,1
64,6,1,1
76,8,1,1
93,10,1,1
106,12,1,1
125,14,1,1
149,16,1,1
171,18,1,1
199,20,1,1
205,21,1,1
40,0,2,1
49,2,2,1
58,4,2,1
72,6,2,1
84,8,2,1
103,10,2,1
122,12,2,1
138,14,2,1
162,16,2,1
187,18,2,1
209,20,2,1
215,21,2,1
43,0,3,1
39,2,3,1
55,4,3,1
67,6,3,1
84,8,3,1
99,10,3,1
115,12,3,1
138,14,3,1
163,16,3,1
187,18,3,1
198,20,3,1
202,21,3,1
42,0,4,1
49,2,4,1
56,4,4,1
67,6,4,1
74,8,4,1
87,10,4,1
102,12,4,1
108,14,4,1
136,16,4,1
154,18,4,1
160,20,4,1
157,21,4,1
41,0,5,1
42,2,5,1
48,4,5,1
60,6,5,1
79,8,5,1
106,10,5,1
141,12,5,1
164,14,5,1
197,16,5,1
199,18,5,1
220,20,5,1
223,21,5,1
41,0,6,1
49,2,6,1
59,4,6,1
74,6,6,1
97,8,6,1
124,10,6,1
141,12,6,1
148,14,6,1
155,16,6,1
160,18,6,1
160,20,6,1
157,21,6,1
41,0,7,1
49,2,7,1
57,4,7,1
71,6,7,1
89,8,7,1
112,10,7,1
146,12,7,1
174,14,7,1
218,16,7,1
250,18,7,1
288,20,7,1
305,21,7,1
42,0,8,1
50,2,8,1
61,4,8,1
71,6,8,1
84,8,8,1
93,10,8,1
110,12,8,1
116,14,8,1
126,16,8,1
134,18,8,1
125,20,8,1
42,0,9,1
51,2,9,1
59,4,9,1
68,6,9,1
85,8,9,1
96,10,9,1
90,12,9,1
92,14,9,1
93,16,9,1
100,18,9,1
100,20,9,1
98,21,9,1
41,0,10,1
44,2,10,1
52,4,10,1
63,6,10,1
74,8,10,1
81,10,10,1
89,12,10,1
96,14,10,1
101,16,10,1
112,18,10,1
120,20,10,1
124,21,10,1
43,0,11,1
51,2,11,1
63,4,11,1
84,6,11,1
112,8,11,1
139,10,11,1
168,12,11,1
177,14,11,1
182,16,11,1
184,18,11,1
181,20,11,1
175,21,11,1
41,0,12,1
49,2,12,1
56,4,12,1
62,6,12,1
72,8,12,1
88,10,12,1
119,12,12,1
135,14,12,1
162,16,12,1
185,18,12,1
195,20,12,1
205,21,12,1
41,0,13,1
48,2,13,1
53,4,13,1
60,6,13,1
65,8,13,1
67,10,13,1
71,12,13,1
70,14,13,1
71,16,13,1
81,18,13,1
91,20,13,1
96,21,13,1
41,0,14,1
49,2,14,1
62,4,14,1
79,6,14,1
101,8,14,1
128,10,14,1
164,12,14,1
192,14,14,1
227,16,14,1
248,18,14,1
259,20,14,1
266,21,14,1
41,0,15,1
49,2,15,1
56,4,15,1
64,6,15,1
68,8,15,1
68,10,15,1
67,12,15,1
68,14,15,1
41,0,16,1
45,2,16,1
49,4,16,1
51,6,16,1
57,8,16,1
51,10,16,1
54,12,16,1
42,0,17,1
51,2,17,1
61,4,17,1
72,6,17,1
83,8,17,1
89,10,17,1
98,12,17,1
103,14,17,1
113,16,17,1
123,18,17,1
133,20,17,1
142,21,17,1
39,0,18,1
35,2,18,1
43,0,19,1
48,2,19,1
55,4,19,1
62,6,19,1
65,8,19,1
71,10,19,1
82,12,19,1
88,14,19,1
106,16,19,1
120,18,19,1
144,20,19,1
157,21,19,1
41,0,20,1
47,2,20,1
54,4,20,1
58,6,20,1
65,8,20,1
73,10,20,1
77,12,20,1
89,14,20,1
98,16,20,1
107,18,20,1
115,20,20,1
117,21,20,1
40,0,21,2
50,2,21,2
62,4,21,2
86,6,21,2
125,8,21,2
163,10,21,2
217,12,21,2
240,14,21,2
275,16,21,2
307,18,21,2
318,20,21,2
331,21,21,2
41,0,22,2
55,2,22,2
64,4,22,2
77,6,22,2
90,8,22,2
95,10,22,2
108,12,22,2
111,14,22,2
131,16,22,2
148,18,22,2
164,20,22,2
167,21,22,2
43,0,23,2
52,2,23,2
61,4,23,2
73,6,23,2
90,8,23,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your first use of `boxplot` is unnecessarily creating a plot, you can use

   ```r
   out <- boxplot.stats(sbset$weight)$out
   ```

   for a little efficiency.
2. You are interested in the presence of rows, but `length(sbset)` will return the number of *columns*. I suggest instead `nrow` or `NROW`.

   ```r
   if (NROW(out) > 0) {
     boxplot(sbset$weight)
     # ...
   } else {
     # ...
   }
   ```